# Finishing university and not sure if I want to work in my field or to continue my dad's business

Tags: inheritance, career

As context, I'm an electrical engineering student currently working on my bachelor thesis. Also, my dad owns a business that process flat glass by doing cuts, shapes, etc. with the majority of the process automatized.

So, I'm struggling of what to do... I enjoy both things, I was a good student and built great relationships at Uni and also I've been helping him since I was like 9 years old, doing simple stuff like cleaning, move small glasses, for example until now where I can apply something I learned while studying like fixing machines (VFDs, control and power wiring, etc).

At one hand, I (will) have this career where I can work in a field that I enjoy and probably will have a more relaxed life in comparison of being independent. However, in the hypothetical case I work with my father, I would have a business that it's already established and would continue my father's hard work.

Of course I don't expect to receive a final answer about this but I would love to read some recommendations or things to think about in order to clear my mind or to have a better understanding about what things I should consider to make this "decision".

Comment: Do you know the income potential and longevity of your father's business? Is your father looking to retire in the near future?

Comment: not VtC or downvoted but I'm pretty sure this isn't on topic here and if it is then it is still too broad.

Comment: Generally speaking, owning a successful business will make you far more money in the long run than as an employee. It's also harder to sell a business where the owner contributes a lot to its success. Passing a business onto your kids is a great solution. You should seriously consider working for Dad, especially if it's something you'll enjoy and excel at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned in comments, this is a broad subject and may attract opinionated answers; however, I shall share my views. First, you need to do a growth potential analysis of your father's business and its earning potential in the long run; your father may be able to provide you a view into this since as a businessman he would have done his analysis.

If the prospects of the business are good, you may think about taking up the business ultimately; however, before doing that, it would probably be good to have a few years (3-5) or slightly longer (depending on when your father is planning to retire) exposure to the workplace and the industry of your choice. A few years of work experience is a good thing to have as you will learn many things in a work place that will be immensely beneficial to you [like team handling, inter-personnel relations, money management, marketing/sales (of yourself, your work, team ...) and perhaps a bit of office politics :)] once you join the family business.

So one option could be to work in the industry for some years and then join the family business.